# Is Wikipedia's example of parallelism incorrect?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, parallelism

As of this writing, [Wikipedia's article about parallelism in grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_(grammar)) includes these examples:

---

Lacking parallelism:

> The dog ran across the yard, jumped over the fence, and sprinted away.

Parallel:

> He likes to play baseball and to run.

---

But they both have the same issue: no object in "to run" and "sprinted away", respectively. Whatever the first example is lacking, the second example is lacking just as much, but they are classified differently.

Comment: The Wikipedia page itself address this very issue: "The final phrase of the [dog] example does not include a definite location, such as "across the yard" or "over the fence"; rewriting to add one completes the sentence's parallelism." It's incomplete parallelism, not unparallel.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie In math, things are either parallel or they are not parallel, in which case they are unparallel. "Unparallel" does not imply "orthogonal". I used "unparallel" to mean "lacking parallelism", but I can update the question in order to stick with Wikipedia's terminology.

Comment: @MWB Grammar isn't math, and the analogy is not perfect.

Comment: @Barmar FYI "unparallel" is in the dictionary. It just means "not parallel".

Comment: @MWB Yes, but in grammar, parallel is not black and white like it is in geometry. As the other comment says, there are variations like "incomplete parallelism". In your example, there's parallelism in the verbs, but not indirect objects.

Comment: It really depends on whether you're analyzing it as [verb phrase] or [verb] [indirect object].

Comment: @Barmar Grammarly defines parallelism as *"two or more phrases or clauses in a sentence that have the same grammatical structure."* Everywhere else I look, I see a similar definition. There are no degrees of parallelism, or relative parallelism with respect to some aspect.

Comment: But as I pointed out, "grammatical structure" isn't precisely defined, because it depends on how finely grained you're specifying the structure.

Comment: There are definitely degrees of parallelism. *She likes to throw frisbees and jump rope* is more parallel than *She likes to throw frisbees and jump on the trampoline*, which is more parallel than *She likes throwing frisbees and to take long walks through the woods.*

Comment: @Nuclear Hoagie Excellently put. I find 'The dog ran across the yard, jumped over the fence, and sprinted away.' perfectly acceptable, and I think 'lacking parallelism' is incorrect here. 'Lacking perfect parallelism', maybe.

Comment: There's a difference between acceptability in terms of grammar and paralellism in terms of sentence structure.

Comment: The dog [past simple verb + locative], [past simple verb + locative], and [past simple verb + locative]... ***Looks parallel to me!*** He likes [*to*-infinitive + object if required] and [*to*-infinitive + object if required]... ***Looks parallel to me!*** He likes to [bare infinitive + object if required] and [bare infinitive + object if required]... ***Looks parallel to me!*** (That article is not top notch.)

Answer (score 1):

To summarise the comments above (and applying parallelism to the first comment):

- The Wikipedia page itself address this very issue: "The final phrase of the [dog] example does not include a definite location, such as "across the yard" or "over the fence"; rewriting to add one completes the sentence's parallelism." It's incomplete parallelism, not non-parallelism.                                                                                                                         [Nuclear Hoagie]
- [I]n grammar, parallel is not black and white like it is in geometry. As the other comment says, there are variations like "incomplete parallelism". In your example, there's parallelism in the verbs, but not indirect objects.                                                                                                                           [Barmar]
- *BUT* Grammarly defines parallelism as "two or more phrases or clauses in a sentence that have the same grammatical structure." Everywhere else I look, I see a similar definition. There are no degrees of parallelism, or relative parallelism with respect to some aspect.                                                                                                                           [MWB]
- *REBUT* But as I pointed out, "grammatical structure" isn't precisely defined, because it depends on how finely grained you're specifying the structure.                                                                                                                            [Barmar]
- There are definitely degrees of parallelism.

*She likes to throw frisbees and jump rope*                                is more parallel than

*She likes to throw frisbees and jump on the trampoline*,      which is more parallel than

*She likes throwing frisbees and to take long walks through the woods*.

[Peter Shor]

Comment: Parallelism has also to be seen in conjunction with zeugma: 'He held his breath and the catch' is unacceptable in serious writing. There are purely semantic constraints too: 'He continues to snore and to read' is a juxtaposition needing unusual context to stop it being ridiculous.